# Ruby Datamapper and SQLite: Display Results

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ruby-datamapper

I'm using Datamapper+SqLite. I need to use a direct query like so:

```
adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
adapter.execute("SELECT * FROM stuff")
```

How do I see the output of this thing? I see type DataObjects::Sqlite3::Result in irb? Also, any recommendations on how to see SQLite results, ala PHPMyAdmin for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `adapter.select`. `execute` is meant for operations that do not return results.

Example:

```
> adapter.select('select * from posts')
=> [#<struct id=1, title="T1", body="B1">, 
    #<struct id=2, title="T2", body="B2">]
```

You can see the documentation on the different adapter methods here:
http://rdoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-do-adapter/DataMapper/Adapters/DataObjectsAdapter

But if all need is just a pure SQLite adapter then you should be looking at something like the `sqlite3` gem instead: http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3